# How to read OS X *.icns file with Java

Tags: java, macos, graphics

I want to read *.icns files in OS X into a BufferedImage. Help

Answer (score 4):

Try this: http://code.google.com/p/appengine-awt/source/browse/trunk/apache-sanselan/src/main/java/org/apache/sanselan/formats/icns/IcnsDecoder.java?spec=svn8&r=8

Which is actually from: http://incubator.apache.org/sanselan/site/index.html

Comment: It's here now: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/imaging/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/imaging/formats/icns/IcnsDecoder.java?view=markup Thank you very much. It's going to help me to make an .app file under GNU Linux and Windows: https://sourceforge.net/p/tuer/tickets/9/#c109

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert ICNS to another image type first, and after load this image you can delete it. This is how to convert PNG to ICNS, so you just need to do in the opposite way:

```
public static void Png(File png, File icns) throws IOException{
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(png));
    ImageIconAs(image, icns);
}

public static void ImageIconAs(ImageIcon ii, File icns) throws IOException{IconAs((Icon)ii,icns);}

public static void IconAs(Icon icon, File icns) throws IOException{
        if (icon != null) {
                BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );
                Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
                icon.paintIcon(new Canvas(), g, 0, 0 );
                g.dispose();
                File outputfile = new File("temp000.png");
                ImageIO.write(bi, "png", outputfile);
                execTerminal(new String[]{ "sips", "-s", "format", "tiff", 
                        "temp000.png","--out", "temp000.tiff" });  
                File apaga2 = new File("temp000.png");
                apaga2.delete();
                execTerminal(new String[]{ "tiff2icns", "-noLarge", 
                        "temp000.tiff", icns.getAbsolutePath()});
                File apaga = new File("temp000.tiff");
                apaga.delete();
        }
    }

static void execTerminal(String[] cmd){
        int exitCode = 0;
        try {
            exitCode = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd).waitFor();
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        catch (IOException e) {
            if (exitCode != 0) System.out.println("ln signaled an error with exit code " + exitCode);
        }
    }
```

You just need to use this to call the action:

Png(png_file,icns_file);

Answer (score 0):

You can youse [IconManager](https://github.com/oleg-cherednik/IconManager). It works with following icons formats:

- ***.ico** - Windows Icon
- ***.icl** - Windows Icon Library
- ***.icns** - Macintosh Icon