# How to get the icon of an application on mac? Java

Tags: java, macos

I am trying to get the image of a file on mac, But i cant find any answers
There is some code that works on windows.

```
String s = "c:/windows/regedit.exe";
File file = new File(s);

sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder sf =
        sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder.getShellFolder(file);
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(sf.getIcon(true));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no clear-cut answer for this. You'll have to do some investigation yourself. If you have an Application in Finder, right-click and choose 'Show package contents'. In the Contents folder, search for the Info.plist file. You'll find an entry containing `CFBundleIconFile` like this (I took TextEdit as an example):

```
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>Edit.icns</string>
```

Go inside the Resources folder, and there you will find the .icns file. You can find information on how to do that in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757677/how-to-read-os-x-icns-file-with-java).